# How do I represent this FOR loop in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

How do I represent this structured English 'code' in Python code?

Structured English:

> FOR NoOfGamesPlayed <-- 1 TO NoOfGamesInMatch Do

I can do it in VB.NET:

```
For NoOfGamesPlayed = 1 To NoOfGamesInMatch
```

I'm confused on how to do it in Python.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) for `for`?  It has an example of what you are looking for.

Comment: I did, my silly problem was that I couldn't figure out what the structured English stuff meant. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for NoOfGamesPlayed in range(1, NoOfGamesInMatch+1):
    # do stuff
```

But note that Python uses 0-based indexing, not 1-based indexing.

So for a list of 5 elements, the valid indices are `[0]` through `[4]`.

Comment: Thank you. The work we're given isn't meant to be used in Python really, which is why it gets confusing at times.